# ReactJs is downloading packages really slow on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, server

I have a reactjs application that is taking a really long time to download the packages on server. When I run it with npm run dev locally, the same package with 11.6mb locally takes 0.7s while on the server is taking 11 minutes.

All my routes are already with lazy loads, I don't know what it can be. I am running in a docker container with the same npm run dev. The same vm is running my backend service and it is working fine.

I'll put my package.json and vite.config.js below.

```
{
  "name": "dashboard-front",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/my-lib.umd.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/my-lib.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/my-lib.js",
      "require": "./dist/my-lib.umd.cjs"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@turf/turf": "^6.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "firebase": "^9.21.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.15.0",
    "plotly.js-dist-min": "^2.24.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.41.5",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.0.25",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.6.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-select": "^5.7.3",
    "react-sliding-side-panel": "^2.0.3",
    "react-svg": "^16.1.12",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.2",
    "vite-plugin-fast-react-svg": "^0.4.0"
  }
}
```

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { svgPlugin } from "vite-plugin-fast-react-svg";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgPlugin()
  ],
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 3000,
    cors: false,
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    }
  },
  preview: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5000,
    strictPort: true,
    cors: false
  },
  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1000 * 500,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
            return 'vendor';
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /reactapp

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  reactapp:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: yarn dev
    environment:
```

Comment: Can you `RUN npm ci` in your Dockerfile so that all of the dependencies are included in your image?  This would mean you just need to `docker pull` the image on to the server, and you do not need to re-download the dependencies every time you run it.  Make sure you do not overwrite the image content with volume mounts.

Comment: I tried that but things look the same. When I check the nertwork in the chrome inspection, the waterfall shows packages downloading in a really slow pace. I'll update the question with the Dockerfile and docker-compose

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by _"downloading packages"_. Do you mean the `npm ci` step? Also, I wouldn't recommend mixing `npm` and `yarn`; they're separate package managers and do things differently with `node_modules`

Comment: When you press F12, go in Network and it shows the Waterfall with the request tme, size, status. It keeps downloading plotly.js for 12 minutes, 11mb, until my page opens

Comment: Downloading from where? Anything that happens in your browser has little to do with how your app is built. Are you sure you haven't enabled [network throttling](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#throttling) in your dev tools?

Comment: I'm sure network throttling is not enabled. I don't have the answer where it is downloading from, I'm telling what dev tools is showing. It says it hasn't finished downloading, show the time and size growing in the waterfall and taking an enormous amount of time to open the page on the server and I don't know why